# CSS left: -50% causing IE7 to ignore width

Tags: html, css, layout, internet-explorer-7

A [fully working example is availiable here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ers7R/5/). I **strongly** encourage you to look here as the CSS is kind of large, and I didn't want to paste it here (making my question hard to read).

I have a horizontally centered tabstrip on my site, the idea is the UL/LI items are centered on the page and I have a solution that up until very recently (looked) like it worked on all browser configurations.

The html for this is actually quite simple:

```
<div id="tabContainer">
    <ul>
        <li style="width: 190px;"><span><a href="#">Tab One with more text</a></span></li>
        <li style="width: 190px;"><span><a href="#">Tab Two</a></span></li>
        <li style="width: 190px;"><span><a href="#">Tab Three is wide</a></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

- Each `<li>` is a tab, it's got left padding for the left rounded tab stuff.
- Each `<span>` has right padding for the right rounded tab stuff.
- Finally the `<a>` generally fills up the remainder making for a large click target.
- Each Item is manually styled with a `width: 190px` which keeps thier widths uniform (for a nice visual look, this is customized by the site code so it's in a `style` vs a `class`.

*The CSS:*

- The CSS works off a simple concept, the `<ul>` is shifted 50% right, and the `<li>` is shifted 50% left (`left: -50%;`) to put them always in the center of the master container.
- The tabs overlap a bit using negative margin & z-index so the corner pieces criss-cross (done in the background image which isn't important here)

**The Problem**

IE7 decides that it's not going to listen to the explicit `style="width: 190px"`, even if `!important` is added to it. However, this only seems to happen when `left: -50%` is present on the `<li>` item. If that style is removed the tabs shift to the right (wrong location, but correct fixed width).

*To me, this seems like it's unrelated* as there's nothing the `left: -50%` would cause the items to collide with forcing them to go to thier minimum width.

This setup works correctly and is tested in:

- IE8
- IE9
- FF3.6
- FF5
- Chrome Stable (v13)*
- Chrome Beta (v14)*
- Safari 3

*As of July 18th, 2011

---

So, what could be causing this? Why is it happening? How can I fix it? I've tried all sorts of tweaks, and cannot get it to obey the width...

---

Image so you can SEE the problem side-by-side:

[Problem http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/3686/ie7centertabsproblem.png](http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/3686/ie7centertabsproblem.png)

Comment: Are you running a true IE7 install? It's at least working fine for me on IETester, even in IE6. It does look a little over-engineered though, and if you're up for dropping the current code I'm sure thirtydot will nail it :)

Comment: Are you particularly attached to that method of centering the `li`s? What I'm saying is, can I center them with a different technique?

Comment: @Wesley: The Center Tab isn't narrower than the left/right ones? I'm using the IE7 Document/Browser Mode in IE9(Win7) & also having the isssue confirmed in IETester IE7 on WinXP. Let me post pictures of the problems.

Comment: @thirtydot: I'm open to suggestions, the key is the tabs overlap and are z-index adjusted to look correct.

Comment: Thanks for posting your code. I had a similar problem that `left: -0%;` fixed for me. I didn't think to add a negative value to `left` until I saw your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest putting `style="min-width:190px; max-width:190px;"` instead of `style="width:190px;"`. It works fine for me in IE7 document/browser mode.

Answer (score -2):

IE 7 who uses it anyway ?!?

You culd try to use em instead of pixels there is a good em converter here:
http://pxtoem.com/

Comment: -1 Unfortunately we still have 10% of our traffic on IE7, we can't just ignore them.

Comment: Ok, thumbs up for that. But why use width at all ?

Created a fiddle for you, hope it  helps:http://jsfiddle.net/msgSw/1/

Comment: The width is in the DOM because the DOM is generated by a configurable control.

Comment: Also may I note, javascript requests for dimensions is a non-performant operation. It usually will trigger a reflow to calculate the width/height of an element, the `jQuery magic` in your example will evidently add to the page load time, especially if there's more like it and they're called a lot. In general I avoid using javascript to "fix" what CSS lacks if at all possible, especially if it's just one browser being broken. Also as a side note, your jQuery will not update if the browser window size is adjusted.